# JSoup Post Throws 404 For a Working Site

Tags: java, post, jsoup, minecraft

I am trying to make something for minecraft that will enable someone to login to their mojang account. I am attempting to do this with jsoup. There is a problem with this however that it throws a 404 error when it redirects to https://account.mojang.com/me which is the normal login page?

```
public String connect() {
    try {
        final Response response = 
                Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/login").execute();
        final Document doc = response.parse();
        final Element authToken = doc.select("input[name^=authenticityToken]").get(0);
        final Map<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();
        final Connection connection = 
                Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/login")
                .data("authenticityToken", authToken.val())
                .data("username", "email")
                .data("password", "password")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true);
        connection.timeout(10000);
        for (final Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
            connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
        }
        final Response postResponse = connection.execute();
        return postResponse.body().toLowerCase();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); return "try again"; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use the whole cookies Map variable using

```
.cookies(cookies);
```

I haven't ever played Minecraft, but in my opinion you should print the response with

```
postResponse.parse();
```

And see if there are no Javascript redirects. As Jsoup is not built for executing Javascript, it won't redirect you to where you want. Also..

```
.followRedirects(false);
```

Have you tried to enable it to true, and see what happens? (I'd try to print the page it gets, and see if Jsoup is redirecting or not)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but it doesn't work. Still throws the 404 error and yes it does redirect. It redirects to https://account.minecraft.net/me which is a 404. It redirects you there anyway if you have logged in via webbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

Does the website have SSL encryption? That could be an issue